# CSS visual error on IE, with wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, wordpress-theming

I'm webmaster of a site mounted in WP 3.3 (with Comodo as default theme) and the latest WP update has produced an aparent CSS problem in IE7+ that I couldn't identify (nor I found in google o related forums). The site is [pastoraluc.cl](http://pastoraluc.cl), and [here's a screenshot](http://pastoraluc.cl/screenshot.png) of the issue I mean.

In other browsers there's no problem, it's only in IE.

Somebody knows how to solve this problem??? Help me please!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a funky character at the beginning of your DOCTYPE declaration that IE is not ignoring. Remove that, clear your cache and your page should load just fine.

Here is a report from the validator:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pastoraluc.cl%2Fweb%2Findex%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Inportant bit:

```
Line 1, Column 1: character "" not allowed in prolog
```

Comment: Hhhmm the problem seems to be another. I've checked the header.php file ([here's the code](http://pastebin.com/xyd9yCc3)) and there's no special char at the beginning. Could be a JS IE oriented function that puts that char?

Comment: Check the encoding of your `header.php` file using a tool like [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and make sure it is set to UTF-8, i had problems with that before.

Comment: @user1128078 - Andres is correct and the validator is reporting the BOM is before the doctype. Anything before the doctype will put IE into quirks mode. Modern browsers will have no problem with this.

Comment: SOLVED!! The problem wasn't (only) in header.php codification, but also in index.php. Both files in UTF-8 without BOM codification and problem solved.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xphantom Im glad :) this issue happens all the time, just make sure to save your stuff using regular UTF-8.